# Jenkins/Phing: Execution of target "lint" failed. Could not create task/type: 'apply'

Tags: php, jenkins, phing

I'm just new to Jenkins and I'm trying to follow this:

http://jenkins-php.org/

but when I try to execute (just using "$ phing") the file "build.xml" it 
says:

> name-of-project > lint:
>
> Execution of target "lint" failed for the following reason: /home/me/ 
>   code/myfirm/build.xml:42:32: Could not create task/type: 'apply'. Make
>   sure that this class has been declared using taskdef / typedef.

Any idea?

Javi

Answer (score 1):

The build.xml provided on http://jenkins-php.org/ is meant to be executed 
as an ant job. 
ant and phing has a compatible xml structure(at least for the main parts, 
like project, task, etc.), but they not 100% compatible with each other. 
it seems that there is no apply task in phing, so I will use ant.

Comment: This is true - however if you do want to use Phing you can use the [PhpLintTask](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixC-OptionalTasks.html#PhpLintTask) rather than calling the executable directly.